# How to update a branch from master with master commits?

Tags: git

Started working on git with a teammate and unable to grasp how to work with branches.
There is a '`master`' branch and I created a branch '`B`' to work on a `module`.
Also I have to frequently get the changes (fetch?) for **some** java classes from the `master` branch.

How to achieve this? Or is it a wrong way to use git?

Comment: It would be helpful to let know why it was down voted. If it is a wrong way to use git, then that is a part of the question as well and I want to know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your module branch has to stay up-to-date regarding master content, you can:

- `git fetch` (that will fetch every `origin` branches)
- `git checkout B` (you are in the 'module' branch)
- `git rebase origin/master` (replay your commits in that branch on top of origin/master)

That works well if the files you are working on in your branch are not the same as the ones updates in master (no conflicts)
Also that works only if you are the only one working on that branch, as it changes its history (which is inconvenient if other have already pulled from that same branch).
If not, you would need to replace the last step by:

```
git merge origin/master
```

You can see more git branches in action in "[Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/)".

---

Note that `git fetch` or `git pull` are separate from the issue of including updates from master.
`git pull` will still fetch, and also merge `origin/B` to `B`: you still then need to merge `origin/master` (or rebase if you are alone on `B`) to get the latest evolution from master into your branch `B`.

If you are several users working on `B`, then a `git pull --rebase` is actually better, as it replays your local (unpushed) commits on top of `origin/B` (avoiding a needless merge commit). Again, that is not related with `origin/master`: a `git merge origin/master` would still be needed to included evolution from `master` into `B`.

Comment: What would happen in case of conflicts? Also, would it behave differently if I used pull instead of fetch and there are conflicts?

Comment: @Srinivas in case of conflicts, you can resolve them, but it is best to make a branch to work on files while are *not* concurrently modified in master. A `git pull` is fine: it still fetches, but also merge `origin/B` to `B`. If you are several users to work on `B`, the a `git pull --rebase` is better, as it replays your local commits (still unpushed) on top of `origin/B` (avoiding a needless merge commit). That does not change the fact that you will need to rebase or merge B with origin/master, to get the updated files from master.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, I'll propose one of them.

So let's say you have your branch B which was created from master. Your team-mate makes some changes somewhere else and those changes end up in master so you need those changes in B as well. First thing you'd need to do is to fetch the remote where that master is (e.g. origin):

```
git fetch origin
```

After running this command, your local git will be aware of the changes that have been carried out in origin. Now you'd need to merge those changes into B. One way to do it is by means of a git rebase:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This process could lead into conflicts, which you'd need to fix. Fixing conflicts is not the point of this question, but you may want to read about --skip, --abort and --continue in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.